# Java File sometimes works and sometimes does not work

Tags: java, file, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to make a sentiment analysis of a sentence. I am reading word's positive and negative values and then showing the result to the user as entered sentence is positive or negative. However, it works for some sentences ang gives exception for some other and I am really confused about it. My code is below. All implementations are done through this class. What should I do to solve it ?

And I have file something like
boring 0.1 0.5
good   0.6 0.4
.
.
.
When I write a boring book
the output 
This sentence is negative

When I write a terrible car I get

a terrible car

```
File does not contain this word.!

 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

 at SentimentAnalysis.posOrNeg(SentimentAnalysis.java:86)

 at SentimentAnalysis.main(SentimentAnalysis.java:121)
```

My file's content is

a 0.8 0.8

beautiful 0.3 0.01

car 0.1 0.1

boring 0.01 0.02

book 0.2 0.18

baby 0.8 0.6

cute 0.6 0.4

terrible 0.3 0.4

Comment: Will you be able to provide us with the exception that you are getting?

Comment: And Also please tell us how the input file looks like rather than describing it, you may give us a snippet of it

Comment: I'm betting on `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` where you try to blindly access `parts[0], parts[1],` and `parts[2]` without verifying that you actually split the line into three parts first.

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan I added an edit.

Comment: 1) what you want to achieve ?
2) What are your inputs to this program?

Comment: bro, you got a NullPointerException and "I amn really confused about it." the stack trace tells you what the problem is and where it is... do you really need input from the StackOverflow community?

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan It tries to find whether a given sentence is positive or negative by using naive beyas approach

Comment: You have to handle the null case if 'a' is null.

Comment: why'd you remove the code?

Answer (score 3):

Judging by what's happening with your error:

```
Probability a = s.findProbabilities(words[k]);  
pos = pos*a.positive;   //ERROR LINE
```

the only reason why you'd get a null reference exception on that line is if `a` is `null`

in your `findProbabilities` method, you do a while loop which does some sort of searching.  I didn't look too deeply into it because that's not the important part.  The important part, is that it's possible for that method to return `null` if it doesn't find a match.

you can't access `a.positive` if `a` is null.  You have to handle the null case.  It can be something as simple as

```
if(a != null)
{
    pos = pos*a.positive;
    neg = neg*a.negative;
}
else
{
    // whatever you want to do if you can't find a
}
```